# Compile a program with using clang API

Tags: c++, c, clang

I built llvm with clang on Windows using mingw (Windows 8 64-bit, MinGW 20120426):

```
./configure --disable-docs --enable-optimized --enable-targets=x86,x86_64 && make && make install
```

Build success.

Now I want compile simple program using clang-c API:

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex (false,true);
}
```

Run gcc:

```
gcc 1.cpp -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include -LC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib -lclang -lstdc++
```

Compile ok, but link failed:

```
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::~MutexImpl()'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x394): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x435): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x464): more undefined references to `clang::SourceManager::isBeforeInTranslationUnit(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation) const' follow
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `clang::SourceManager::getMacroArgExpandedLocation(clang::SourceLocation) const'
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libclang.a(CIndex.o):CIndex.cpp:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `clang::ASTUnit::Save(llvm::StringRef)'
...
```

over 700 lines.

```
$ llvm-config.exe --version
3.1
$ llvm-config.exe --prefix
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you found the answer to your problem, you're welcome (and encouraged) to add it as an answer and mark that answer as correct. Doing so will make this thread more useful to other users that come across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Add all params from llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs all

I write makefile like [this](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/blob/master/makefile)

```
CXX := g++
LLVMCOMPONENTS := all
RTTIFLAG := -fno-rtti
LLVMCONFIG := llvm-config
CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVMCONFIG) --cxxflags) $(RTTIFLAG)
LLVMLDFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVMCONFIG) --ldflags --libs $(LLVMCOMPONENTS))
SOURCES = 1.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXES = $(OBJECTS:.o=)
CLANGLIBS = \
                -lclang\
                -lclangTooling\
                -lclangFrontendTool\
                -lclangFrontend\
                -lclangDriver\
                -lclangSerialization\
                -lclangCodeGen\
                -lclangParse\
                -lclangSema\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore\
                -lclangAnalysis\
                -lclangARCMigrate\
                -lclangEdit\
                -lclangAST\
                -lclangLex\
                -lclangBasic\
                $(shell $(LLVMCONFIG) --libs)

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXES)

%: %.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $< $(CLANGLIBS) $(LLVMLDFLAGS)
```

Complile and link success.